# patchForObject how to?

Tags: resttemplate, json-patch

I would like to send an HTTP PATCH request via Spring RestTemplate containing an array of operations represented by following object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JsonOperation {
    private String op;
    private String path;
    private String value;
}
```

considering following code:

```
List<JsonOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();
operations.add(new JsonOperation("replace", "/path1", "value1"));
operations.add(new JsonOperation("replace", "/path2", "value2"));
operations.add(new JsonOperation("replace", "/path3", "value3"));
```

is it possible to do the reqeust using restTemplate as follows?

```
restTemplate.patchForObject(url+"/toPatch/"+toPatchId, operations, ResponseEntity.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of a Bug the default RestTemplate of Spring does not send Http Patch requests.

As work around the `org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` can be used to overrride the RestTemplate:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate httpComponentsClientRestTemplate() {
    final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(3000);
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(3000));
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```